# Time Complexity - nested for loop

Tags: time, big-o, complexity-theory

For the given code, whats the time complexity in bigO notation:

```
for(i=n; i >= 1; i /=2)
 for(j=i; j>=1; j/=2)
     x = i+j;
```

The first loop runs Log N times, how about the second loop? 
Is it (Log N * Log N) ?

I am confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asymptotically, we can say that complexity of second loop is O(logn) and  In each iteration of first Loop, second loop iterates once, so the complexity will be logn*logn that is (logn)^2

Comment: what about `log(N)*log(log(N))` ?

Comment: can you explain please?

Comment: Admittedly you are right. Say log2(n) = 10. Then first loop iterates 10 times, inner does 10+9+8+7...+1, which is quadratic in relation to what we took to be log(N), so we have (log(N))^2